# Synchronise Samba 4.4 passwords with the Unix password database

Tags: samba, freebsd, pam, samba4, smb-conf

I run a small Samba **4.4** server, and I would like to keep the Samba password database in sync with the Unix password database.  I would like the Samba password to be updated when a user changes their password with the traditional Unix `passwd` program.  I do not think I want to go through the complexity of configuring the machine to use winbind.

It appears you used to be able to use this using the `pam_smbpass` module, and most of the documentation I find refers to this.  However, it appears this was removed in Samba 4.4 with [this commit message](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/commit/3c00e8d76a2ef6194a8ce522c15853e5b8e9262b):

> pam_smbpass: REMOVE this PAM module
>
> This pam module causes GPLv3, thread-unsafe Samba code to be directly
>   loaded into the address space of many system services.  The code in
>   question was not expected to run in this context, and while using the
>   Samba, rather than the system password file is a admirable goal, this
>   needs to be done over inter-process communication, such as is done by
>   pam_winbind.
>
> pam_winbind is not a total replacement, as the migrate functionality
>   used to keep the Samba password up to date with the system password is
>   not present, but otherwise can provide essentially the same services.
>
> Andrew Bartlett
>
> Signed-off-by: Andrew Bartlett  Reviewed-by:
>   Jeremy Allison

I believe the functionality I want is the "migrate functionality used to keep the Samba password up to date with the system password" which is the one thing that `pam_winbind` apparently doesn't provide.  What other simple options do I have to manage Samba passwords with the normal Unix utilities?

---

This server runs FreeBSD 10.3 and Samba 4.4, however I welcome any suggestion, even those that aren't FreeBSD specific.

Comment: The typical approach is to have all user accounts in LDAP instead, I think.

Comment: LDAP is something else I was hoping to avoid, since it's a small standalone server.

Comment: Is having a local LDAP server really the solution to this ? i mean... who is keeping the samba passwords synchronized with the system (linux) passwords when the users are supposed to use a single cli to set their passwords ? (like passwd) what single command are the users supposed to use which still obeys the pam stack to ensure the password quality, history etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get something working with [pam_script](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_script)

Comment: I'll look into that.  This link seems to have some information about issues someone had using `pam_exec` for this: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-November/406858.html

Comment: This page also documents some issues that prevented someone from using `pam_exec` for the password change use case: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/PamExecWhyNot.  Apparently, as of 2016, `expose_authtok` isn't supported when you're changing passwords, so you can't get at the new one.

Comment: Fine, how about pam_script?

Comment: I'm going to look into it.  I just wanted to gather those links here in case they help someone.